# Get request in sharepoint _api/web/siteusers

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've created an app in sharepoint and want this app to query the site users list: 
https://test.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers. I've given the app the following permissions in the app's Permission Request XML using this URL:
https://test.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx

```
    <AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

So basically I trigger a flow when something is added in a sharepoint list and I get the access token by running a post 
request to https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/common/tokens/OAuth/2
combining the clientid,appid and tenantid from the sharepoint app I created, in the body of the request.

I then use this access code below to query the site user list

When I run a get request in flow or in fiddler:

```
GET https://test.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json;odata=nometadata
Host: test.sharepoint.com
Authorization: Bearer <access code>
```

I get the following:

> "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." or {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. 
>   You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"` to elevate privileges.

Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/app-only-elevated-privileges-sharepoint-add-in) link for more details.